# Diacritcs problem in text mode : combining accent

Tags: fonts, accents, combine

I'm inventing a language requiring double accents, or diacritics. The problem is that a diacritic can't go over a special letter, and will be fixed next to it, not on. For instance, when using \textaolig : ꜵ, we have : 
    ̏ ꜵ &  ̏ Ꜵ

Furthermore, if I want to use ogonek, I have to load [T1]{fontenc}, but for double left accent, I have to use [T4]{fontenc}, that seems not to be compatible. How can we use both on the same time ?

Sorry for my english,
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I create a macro, `\dblacc{}` for adding a double accent to characters.  It works even for accenting an ogonek.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,tipx,lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand\dblgr{\setbox0=\hbox{x}%
  \setbox2=\hbox{\raisebox{-\ht0}{\`{}\kern-2.7pt\`{}}}\dp2=0pt\box2}
\newcommand\dblacc[1]{\stackengine{0pt}{#1}{\dblgr}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}}
\begin{document}
\k{a}\k{\textaolig}
\dblacc{\textaolig}
\dblacc{\k{\textaolig}}\dblacc{\AE}
\end{document}
```

[image]